# I have an error migrating my tables in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, migration

i'm new here and i have a problem that i cant resolve.

i was creating my migrations with the comand: php artisan make:migration table --create=table

but when i do enter to "php artisan migrate", i have this error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     parse error

all the tables are like this:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CTEquiposMantenciones extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('equipos_mantenciones', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unique();
            $table->integer('equipos_id');
            $table->integer('matenciones_id');
        });
    }   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('equipos_mantenciones');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that in one of migration file is syntactical error. Missing semicolon, improper closed brackets, typos etc...

After running, you probably got this kind of error:

```
$ php artisan migrate
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''name'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/hradecek/laravel/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php on line 18
PHP Stack trace:
...
```

This might give you a hint what went wrong, see especially the part with path to file and line number.

In this specific example, there has been something wrong on **line 18** in file on path **/home/hradecek/laravel/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, i haven't see it

Comment: Glad to hear that, could you please mark the answer as solution :)